# Question regarding sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification

I came across the following line from my Number Theory Text:

"The idea behind the sieve is simple: the primes are the numbers left when all the composites are gone. Then, to find primes remove multiples of $2,$ of $3,$ of $5, \ldots$; if we stop after removing multiples of $N,$ the numbers remaining between $2$ and $N^2$ are precisely the primes less than $N^2$".

My confusion is this: Say we are given a list of numbers, from $2$ to $n$, where $n$ is not the square of any integer. Then by the quoted line, we would remove prime multiples of all primes from 2 to $n^{\frac{1}{2}}$ However, $n$ in this case isn't a perfect square. Would we still be left with all primes by removing multiples of the prime closest to whatever $n^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is?

I have tried to answer this question with the follwoing proof (this proof uses the fact that for all $z \in \mathbb{Z}$, $z$ has a prime divisor $d \leq n^{\frac{1}{2}}$):

$Proof:$ Suppose we have a sequence of integers $2, 3, \ldots, n$. We may eliminate multplies of $2, 3, \ldots , p_k$ where $p_k$ is a prime such that $p_k\leq n^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and there does not exist a prime $p_i$ such that $p_k < p_i \leq n^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Suppose there remains a composite integer $d$. Then $d$ has a prime divisor, say $p_j$, such that $p_j\mid d$ and $p_j\leq d^{\frac{1}{2}}$. If $p_k < p_j$, we have a contradiction. Thus, $p_j \leq p_k$ and $d$ does not remain. Therefore, all integers remaining are prime. $\mathbb{Q.E.D}$

Comment: You’d be left with all primes after removing multiples of all primes $\le\sqrt{n}$, or, equivalently, $\le\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$.

Comment: I see, that last part clears my confusion. Thank you.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Comment: Right. if $m>1$ and $m$ is not prime then $m=ab$ with $1<a<m$ and $1<b<m.$ So $a\le \sqrt m \iff b\ge \sqrt m.$ If $a\le \sqrt m,$ let $p$ be the smallest factor $ f$ of $a$ such that $ f>1.$ Then $p$ is prime, and $p$ is a factor of $m,$ and $p\le \sqrt m.$ E.g. if $10^4<m<10^8$ then $m$ is composite iff $m$ has a prime factor less than $10^4.$